# Can a one way NS Ticket be used as an OV-Chipkaart for P+R Parking in Amsterdam?

Tags: automobiles, netherlands, amsterdam

I will be flying to Amsterdam in a few weeks, renting a car, and then driving to Germany. On my arrival day, I have a few hours before checking into my hotel and am considering dropping the car off at a P+R lot, taking the NS Train into the city centre (hotel is near Sloterdijk) and exploring the city.

On the [City of Amsterdam P+R website](https://www.amsterdam.nl/en/parking/park-and-ride/), parking in a P+R spot is only €1 on weekends, but requires an OV-Chipkaart upon exit to qualify for the discount. Seeing as how I'll only need one ticket to enter the city, and one ticket to get back to my car, it seems unnecessary to get either the personal or the anonymous OV-Chipkaart.

Will my one-way (or return) NS Train ticket count as an OV-Chipkaart at the exit machine for the P+R parking lot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not even sure travelling with the NS would count for the P+R ticket (edit: [your link](https://www.ns.nl/en/door-to-door/consumers/park-ride.html) says it does, but not for the full amount), even if you did it with your own (permanent) OV chipkaart.

Fortunately, there's a good alternative which certainly works: purchase a [P+R GVB return ticket](https://en.gvb.nl/ontdek-amsterdam/pr-retour) and take Metro 51 to Central Station (or any other destination in the city center). Much more flexible than the train!

Comment: Hmm looks like you're right. The [NS Website](https://www.ns.nl/en/door-to-door/consumers/park-ride.html) says it's only a 30% discount. Thanks for the help!